# How can I enable Compose key?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I had a [**Compose Key**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) set to **right** <kbd>**Super**</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>**Windows**</kbd>) key using Gnome keybindings. After upgrading, I seem to have lost the Compose Key function. Where can I enable Compose Key? I can't find any option under *System Settings > Keyboard*.

Comment: Some better explanation for 13.10: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/405689/compose-key-wont-enable

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In **Ubuntu 21.10 and later**, a compose key option has returned to System Settings. In *Settings* navigate to the *Keyboard* section in the left column, then, under the *Special Characters* section, select *Compose Key*. Turn off the *Default Layout*, and select which key you would like to use.

In addition, the method just below (i.e., the 18.04 through 21.04 way) still works, save that the `gnome-tweak-tool` package is now called `gnome-tweaks` (because why not). So use this command instead to install it:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

---

In **Ubuntu 18.04 through Ubuntu 21.04**, since Ubuntu has now adopted the GNOME Desktop, things are more complicated: there is no longer any way to set the compose key within the regular system settings.

You must first download an entirely separate program, GNOME Tweaks. This can be found in Ubuntu Software or can be downloaded with this command via a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once Tweaks is installed, run it. Then hit *Keyboard & Mouse* on the left. In the *Keyboard* section on the right, an option to enable the compose key can be found. By default it is not enabled, so you will need to click on the word *Disabled* (confusingly, the word does not look clickable, but it is), which will open another window. Toggle the switch in the top left of that new window's title bar to enable setting the key.

[image: Compose Key window in Ubuntu 20.04]

Note that there are still limited options for what key can be set: <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>, <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Menu</kbd>, and <kbd>Right Super</kbd>.
If you wish to set it to a key not listed, the solution in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/367802/11317) still works.

---

In **Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04** go to *Keyboard* within *System Settings*. Select the *Shortcuts* tab, then *Typing* from the list on the left. Clicking to the right of the *Compose Key* setting will bring up a menu of different options.

Note that the only options are <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Right Win</kbd>, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Menu</kbd>, and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. If you wish to set it to a key not listed, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/367802/11317).

---

In **Ubuntu 12.04** and earlier, go to *Keyboard Layout* in *System Settings*, then hit the *Options* button on the lower right. You will see one option called *Compose key position*, where you can set it to <kbd>Right Win</kbd> (i.e. right <kbd>Super</kbd>).

Comment: The Ubuntu 18.04 solution still applies, as of Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @Aibara On my 18.04.3 system, gnome tweaks keeps the compose key setting disabled.

Comment: @Jonathan Check my [solution below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190137/635534) to get it to actually enable the setting.

Comment: This does not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Can anybody help here?

Comment: @ElectRocnic I did confirm it works in Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to clarify the instructions a bit. Seems like every release it gets a bit more confusing to do.

Comment: Got working months ago, thanks nevertheless, I made a mistake and did not come back to edit my comment here :)

Comment: As of Sept 2021, gnome-tweak-tool and gnome-tweaks no longer seem to exist. I had to edit gsettings directly as per https://askubuntu.com/a/1337274/580023 .

Answer (score 4):

### In Ubuntu 13.10

In *Keyboard* settings window, under *Shortcuts -> Typing* set **Compose key** to *Right Alt* (or other).
[image: snap1]

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 19.10, and likely anything using `gnome-tweaks` (the current name for gnome-tweak-tool), the UI for enabling the compose key is a little confusing.  First, under Keyboard & Mouse, click the "Disabled" button:

[image: disabled button]

Then this is where the UI is tricky (and utterly indefensible IMHO).  Click the switch widget in the top left of the new window:

[image: switch widget]

Once you do that, it'll let you actually change the setting.

Comment: OMFG. Seriously. That UI. I cannot believe it. I had to come here to figure out why the heck the options were all disabled.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu MATE 18.04 go to *Control Center* → *Keyboard* → *Layouts* → *Options* → *Position of Compose key* and select your choice for the key.

Answer (score 2):

## **In Ubuntu 22.04 and later:**

As of Ubuntu 22.04, `gnome-tweak-tools` or `gnome-tweak` can no longer set the Compose key. Instead, you can set it in the Keyboard panel in the **Settings** application. In the section **Special Characters** you can activate the compose key.

[image: Keyboard -> Special Character Entry -> Compose Key]

Answer (score 1):

### In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

1. Select *System Settings...* from system menu;
   [image: snap1]
2. Select *Keyboard*;
   [image: snap2]
3. Under the tab labelled *Typing* click *Layout Settings*;
   [image: snap3]
4. In keyboard layout window, click <kbd>Options...</kbd> button;
   [image: snap4]
5. Finally in the *Keyboard Layout Options* window select **Key(s) to change layout** and *mark* the binding of your choice. (I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to toggle the layout.)
   [image: snap5]

---

***Useful link:***

- [How can I type accentuated characters like ë? alt. How to use compose keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-e)

*Summary:*

#### Using compose key:

- For `ë` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> keys.

  *(..here you'd have to remember the two character combination)*

#### Using hexadecimal Unicode character code point:

- Press (and release) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then, while underlined ***u*** is displayed, enter the hexadecimal Unicode character code point followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>.

  e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> for ☻ .

  *(..so this one would require you to remember the Unicode number)*

Answer (score 1):

In **ubuntu 18.04** you can try `gnome-tweak-tools`, but
  a) it did not work for me
  b) the options are restricted to fewer keys than possible

If you'd like to use e.g. a combination of <kbd>super</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, you could not do that in the tweak tools. But you can do as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152027/606260) suggests and modify a `dconf` setting:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:lwin-altgr']"
```

For a list of possible options:

```
grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst 
  compose:ralt         Right Alt
  compose:lwin         Left Win
  compose:lwin-altgr   3rd level of Left Win
  compose:rwin         Right Win
  compose:rwin-altgr   3rd level of Right Win
  compose:menu         Menu
  compose:menu-altgr   3rd level of Menu
  compose:lctrl        Left Ctrl
  compose:lctrl-altgr  3rd level of Left Ctrl
  compose:rctrl        Right Ctrl
  compose:rctrl-altgr  3rd level of Right Ctrl
  compose:caps         Caps Lock
  compose:caps-altgr   3rd level of Caps Lock
  compose:102          &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  compose:102-altgr    3rd level of &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  compose:paus         Pause
  compose:prsc         PrtSc
  compose:sclk         Scroll Lock
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I had to edit gsettings directly via the terminal as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1337274/580023):

> Thanks to the previous answers, here is the method that worked for me:
>
> List keyboard settings:
>
> ```
> gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources
> ```
>
> Set the compose key:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt']"
> ```
>
> List possible values for compose key (replace `compose:ralt` with your preferred option):
>
> ```
> grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In Plasma 5, go to *Settings - Input devices - Keyboard - Advanced - Position of Compose key*:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In order to set up the  <kbd>Compose</kbd>  key you must go to (setting -> keyboard -> layout settings -> keyboard settings -> then go to the typing tab -> press and hold the Compose Key setting -> move you mouse down to select the key you want to assign <kbd>Compose</kbd> to. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]