# How to set compose key to pause in 13.10?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 13.10, keyboard-layout, compose-key

In Ubuntu 13.04 I had my compose key set to <kbd>pause</kbd> (by going to `System Settings`, then `keyboard layout`, `option`, and changing the compose key setting). In 13.10 the keyboard settings have been totally rearranged: the compose key is now set by going to `Keyboard` in `System Settings`, hitting the `Shortcuts` tab, then the `Typing` menu.

However, there is no option to select <kbd>pause</kbd>. How can I set the compose key to whatever key I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem and lost a couple of hours trying to resolve it.

I found a solution, based on what can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey.

**This is what you need to do:**

In the terminal type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

After typing your administrator's password, the text editor will open. Find the line that reads:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Enter the desired key value between the quotation marks. In my case it was compose:lwin – to map the left Windows key as compose. In your case it should be: **compose:paus**. So the line should look like this

```
XKBOPTIONS="compose:paus"
```

A list of possible options can be found when you type

```
grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

in the terminal. 
Log out, log in again – should work just fine.

(PS: Why they turned off the possibility to customize this easily in the system settings, still remains an unresolved problem.)

Comment: No clue why the possibilty to customize was removed, but thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need to edit your system files.  `Use dconf-editor` to change `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`, `xkb-options`.  For example, mine reads: `['caps:swapescape', 'altwin:meta_alt', 'compose:prsc']`.

Comment: @P-Nuts thanks, nice hint. This is what bother me with the keyboard thing --- there are at least 4 different places where you can change this and I (and probably no one) knows exactly how they interact. If you have a link... post it there.

Comment: [That answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70788/606260) claims that this answer still works on ubuntu 18.04 but it does not work for me with `compose:lwin-altgr`

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152027/606260) works for me on ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: I'm installing 20.04.1, I need the compose key, but can't get it working. Regardless, thanks for the info. Unfortunately, when copied and pasted your suggestions into a terminal, using "rwin" as the compose key, it didn't work. BTW. I had previously installed the "Tweak-tools". When I launch it all that comes up is the "General" sub-window.