# Bind a key to the 'contextmenu' key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

On most full sized PC keyboards there is a context menu key. See photo below.

[image]

My new laptop doesn't have one of these keys, but I use it all the time. The context menu shows the context menu of the currently selected item, not the item currently underneath the mouse pointer.

My question is, how can I re-map another key combination (preferably CTRL + PrtSc) to perform the same operation?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/389353/how-can-i-set-a-certain-keycode-to-a-key-and-bind-it-to-the-right-action?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Comment: What exactly should the key do? I don't have it :) It seems simply the same as the right- mouseclick, right?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, it opens right-click menu :)

Comment: Ah, in that case, see my answer :)

Comment: Hi Greg, did you notice the answer?

Comment: The context menu shows the context menu of the **currently selected** item, not the item currently underneath the mouse pointer.

Comment: *Due to using a keyboard to navigate, rather than a mouse, the mousepointer will most definitely not be hovering over the icon that is currently selected* - useful to include that in the question...

Answer (score 3):

On my system, I do have a context menu key.

In a terminal, when I run `xev`, which should be present by default on your system as well, I see this output (in part):

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,  
    root 0x96, subw 0x0, time 12548175, (334,-138), root:(588,185),  
    state 0x0, keycode 135 (keysym 0xff67, Menu), same_screen YES,  
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:   
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:   
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,  
    root 0x96, subw 0x0, time 12548242, (334,-138), root:(588,185),  
    state 0x0, keycode 135 (keysym 0xff67, Menu), same_screen YES,  
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:   
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

If you want to know more about `xev`, this maybe informative: [Weekend Project: Configure Your Keyboard Into Submission](https://www.linux.com/learn/weekend-project-configure-your-keyboard-submission)

I suggest you try to bind a convenient spare keyboard shortcut to "Menu" using whichever method your distro provides and see if that works for cases where you know or expect that the right-click effect isn't the same as pressing on the Menu key.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, I'll give it a go now as I'm on my laptop.