# How can I change my keyboard layout to make the PgUp and PgDn keys on my number pad work? (Asus laptop)

Tags: keyboard, kde, laptop, keyboard-layout, asus

I have an Asus TUF A15 which I have dual booted to ubuntu (works brilliantly would recommend). I was looking at trying to use some keyboard shortcuts (Meta + PgUp) but for some reason when I turn off numlock and try to press the key that represents PgUp on on my laptop (number pad 9) it doesn't do PgUp. I do not have any other way of pressing this key on my laptop so I was wondering if there was a way to change the numpad behaviour of my laptop.

I am using KDE Plasma not gnome - but all the gnome apps are still installed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, use `xev` command to find out which key has which code. And there is already the same question in this forum, follow the answer.

Comment: Possible options may be in KDE Keyboard configuration, on Advanced tab check Miscellaneous compatibility options.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka can you please link this other question, I couldn't find it.

Comment: You meant assign new 'PgUp' to another key. That's what I get it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/389353/how-can-i-set-a-certain-keycode-to-a-key-and-bind-it-to-the-right-action

Comment: No, I was asking if I could change what the 9 and 3 keys do.