# How to type "ñ" with a UK keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

How can I type "ñ" with a UK layout using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>?

I'd like to be able to just press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+ and get "ñ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then write the unicode codepoint of the letter, for Ñ it is 00D1 and press <kbd>Space</kbd>. This works for any unicode character in most of the X applications.

Okay so it looks like I only read the title. If you want to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY keylayout.xkb
```

Open the keylayout.xkb with your favourite editor end search for the symbol which has the mapping for <kbd>N</kbd>, something like:

```
    key <AB06> {
    type= "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC",
    symbols[Group1]= [               n,               N,      braceright,               N ]
};
```

And change the third value (e.g. `braceright`) to `ntilde` and the fourt value (e.g. `N`) to `Ntilde` . Save and

```
xkbcomp keylayout.xkb $DISPLAY
```

After this it should work. (For me it does.) But it is only for this session, to make it permanent make a script named `/etc/keylayout.sh` like

```
#!/bin/bash
xkbcomp /etc/keylayout.xkb $DISPLAY
```

Make the script executable `sudo chmod a+x /etc/keylayout.sh` and add the next line to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
session-setup-script=/etc/keylayout.sh
```

Source for the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> method: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension)

Answer (score 5):

The layout *"English (International with AltGr keys)"* has the ñ/Ñ using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>. Others AltGr/with dead keys layouts has the key somewhere, but if you want a surekill [you should use Unicode](https://askubuntu.com/a/389875/169736).

[image]

Comment: This one is the most practical option. With this keyboard I can type in English and Spanish without a problem. All accented vowels can also be produced with AltGr+vowel

Comment: I don't seem to have this layout available (weird). I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: Does not work a German keyboard layout! I have figured out how to type Icelandic, French, Hungarian, even Vietnamese, but the ñ is doomed!

Comment: @DrunkenMaster German != UK layout...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Compose Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), configurable in many systems. The default key combination is <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>