# Does Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa support the Compose-Key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 20.04, gnome-tweak-tool, compose-key

I tried everything I could find in the following links:
[How can I enable Compose key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ComposeKey

However, I still could not get the compose key working on my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.

I use the english (US) keyboard layout, but I need to be able to type Umlauts with the compose key. In Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 it worked just fine and I mapped set and used the super key without any problems.

In 20.04 I tried different keys but none of them worked.

The output from `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` is:
`xkb-options ['compose:rwin', 'eurosign:e', 'esperanto:qwerty']`,
however `sudo vim /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-input-sources` contains `compose:ralt`...

Comment: ẏ€s īt døæs ... I used the method from [using tweak tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key), but I updated from 19.10, maybe the problem is setting the compose key ...

Comment: I would actually like to map it to my right control, which I might have mistakenly thought to be the right super key? However, I tried it with right alt and it did not work, but the output of the command you provided says that this setting was not even recognized by the system so that might be the reason why right alt did not work...

Comment: Now I set it with tweak-tools to the right-control key and it works: Ö Ä Ü € ... nice, thanks! You pointed me in the right direction with the command.

Comment: You could add an answer with the command and that my output contains the wrong key, so I can mark yours as the correct one instead of my own...

Answer (score 7):

Gunnar's comment pointed me into the right direction.

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` shows the current active settings and therefore I was able to find out that I used the wrong key.

Using the `gnome-tweak-tools` I could update the settings accordingly to the right-ctrl which finally worked.

Comment: wow this is ... NOT how this works in September

Comment: Additionally requires `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` since September 2020.

Comment: Is there any explanation for what changed since September 2020? As of November, my compose key (caps lock) stops working. In order to have it recognized again as compose, I have to reset and reapply the dconf setting: `key=/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options; val=$(dconf read $key); dconf reset $key; dconf write $key $val;`

Comment: At least on 20.10, the command no longer works, however `gsettings list-recursively   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` does.

Comment: In 20.04, there is [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206) which caused settings not to be applied anymore.

Comment: (And Alt+F2, `r`, `Enter` reloads the configuration – this is quite helpful)

Comment: As of Ubuntu 22.04, gnome-tweak-tools can no longer set the Compose key.  Instead, you can set it in the Keyboard panel in the Settings application.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the previous answers, here is the method that worked for me:

List keyboard settings:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources
```

Set the compose key:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:paus']"
```

List possible values for compose key:

```
grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

Comment: This works for me (July 2021)

Comment: This works for me as of September 2021 on 20.04.3 LTS. ♥

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer to use the command line, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361268/how-to-set-compose-key-to-pause-in-13-10/367802#367802).  Worked like a charm for me on U20.04.

If you prefer to use the GUI, and don't mind installing a package just for defining the compose key, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-70788).

Comment: This have probably worked for earlier versions, but not for 20.04.