# Gnome: show alternate characters by a long press on a keyboard letter

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus

On macOS devices, I love the feature of having alternate characters shown by a long press of any key (see screenshot attached).

[image: Screenshot of long press of letter E on macOS]

As I use a DVORAK US keymap on my loved Thinkpad, I do not have access to accentuate character I use in French unless I switch to AZERTY keymap.

Switching often is a bit painful and a big source of mistakes. I hope to have a similar feature in my Wayland graphical environment.

I didn’t found yet something that fits my need, and I consider implementing it with [IBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus), without knowing what could be a good way to start hacking on it.

Comment: have you considered using `Tweaks` and setting a `Compose` key from which you can utilise special characters (such as `Compose` key + e + ' to produce é?) The compose key latches so you don't have to perform keyboard finger gymnastics. I use this all the time to type French on a UK keyboard.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231840/

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that that mechanism is present with the Screen Keyboard feature (OSK), at least on Wayland.