# Compose key won't enable

Tags: shortcut-keys, 13.10, compose-key

Right now, I'm trying to enable my compose key to type characters with accents. It wont enable.

I'm in the system settings panel, and all it says is:

Compose key............................................................ Disabled

However, when I click on one that does have something currently in it, it gives me the option to create a new one:

Switch to previous source ................................. New accelerator

It never shows the option to define a "New Accelerator" for the compose key, rather it just stays in the 'disabled' mode.

Please help!

Running: Ubuntu 13.10

Computer: Acer Aspire 5250

All updates are enabled, except for preliminary.

Answer (score 3):

For the compose key, you have to select a key from the drop down list displayed while clicking the disabled option.

[image]