# Type @ symbol with alt+64

Tags: shortcut-keys, special-characters

I wanted to know if there is a way to type an @ symbol by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>64</kbd> like in Windows. I use both Spanish and English keyboard layouts so I find it useful.

Comment: You can press `Shift + Ctrl + u` and then followup by the character's hex-unicode-number (for `@` it's `0040` while `64` as `&#64` is used in html code). This method requires you to remember the unicode numbers. Another way is to [enable compose keys](http://askubuntu.com/a/418589/212123). With this enabled, for `@` I can use `Compose + A + T` (note `A` = `Shift + a` and not just `a`; like wise for `T`.)

Comment: @rusty Why not add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Dan, the_Seppi has already answered it.. while for compose key method the [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/418589/212123) should help. :)

Answer (score 5):

Like Windows uses the Alt-Combos for ASCII, Ubuntu knows a similar input method for Unicode characters.

To enter the *@* sign, which would be Unicode U+40 (hexadecimal!), press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>.

This works the same for all Unicode chars, like U+2744 for a snowflake.

Comment: You may have to release <shift> after typing the U. You can even release <CTRL> as well, <space> signals the end of your code number.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Thanks, I didn't know that so far

Comment: You may need [IBus as the input method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050341/349837)