# Why has my Ctrl+Shift+U key for Unicode input stopped working?

Tags: keyboard, unicode-entry

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and type numbers, nothing happens. Holding down <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't help, either.

I've tried running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It seems things have changed since this question was answered.  I've tried all these answers in 22.10 Kinetic and none of them work.

Answer (score 9):

It hasn't stopped working in general, but the way it works may have led you to think that it has stopped working. When one types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> an underscored letter u appears at the insertion point. This may lead a person (e.g., myself, at first) to think that he has entered an underscored letter u, whereas in fact the underscored letter u indicates the Unicode-entry mode has been activated. If one subsequently keys in a Unicode code point (i.e., the hexadecimal numeral for the character) and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the unicode character will appear.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a "heavy black heart" Unicode character.

Demonstration: ❤

Comment: The underlined U does not appear.

Comment: It stopped working for me too, must be some issue with GTK

Comment: Just tested in gedit in Ubuntu 15.04. Worked fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04. It used to work on earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Confirmed for Ubuntu 18.08. --> ❤

Comment: By the way, this answer bypasses the question entirely because the OP clearly knows how the `ctrl`+`shift`+`u` is supposed to work.  It has stopped working for me since I upgraded to 20.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>[Unicode hexadecimal number](http://unicode-table.com/)</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> stop working in Ubuntu 15.10+ is because input method is by default [XIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Input_Method) instead of [iBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) (which is odd since XIM is obsolete and [iBus already implement XIM protocol](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/blob/master/util/IMdkit/XimProto.h)). By changing this they broke this useful shortcut.

To fix it, go to:

1. On **GNOME Shell** (17.10+, check with `wmctrl -m`):
   *Settings* → *Region & Language* → *Manage Installed Languages* → *Language* tab.

   <sup>On **Unity**: *System Settings... → Language Support*.</sup>
2. Keyboard input method system, change it to iBus.
   [image: screenshot]
3. Reboot (`reboot`)

#### Reference

- [gnome - Understanding & setting up different input methods - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/understanding-setting-up-different-input-methods)

Comment: It hasn't stopped working. Please check the solution from jdthood

Comment: @somethis, it _has_ stopped working for many of us.  The solution from jdthood isn't a solution: It's the way it was supposed to work, and I believe the OP knew this already with his question (he said "stopped working").  I can't get it to work in comments here, gmail, other edit fields, any editor, basically everywhere it used to work in 18.{mumble}.

Comment: I switched to XIM as the language input method and rebooted.  No change.  ctrl+shift+U still does nothing.

Comment: @Jason Step 2 says _change it to iBus._

Comment: I've switched it to iBus but it does nothing.  Shift+ctrl+u does nothing.

Comment: I had simillar trouble; changing to iBus seemed to do nothing.  Then I saw Jason's comment  above and rebooted.  (Despite Jason's having said that he'd done that ....).  Anyhow:   (1) changing to iBus, and (2) rebooting worked for me.