# Ctrl-Shift-U doesn't work on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: keyboard, 15.10

The default install of Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't have the UNICODE input method working like on previous versions. After reinstalling (and keeping the same configuration files) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> still doesn't allow me to type UNICODE characters.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: [Answered here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050341/349837) and maybe duplicate of that question. System will generate it but if you prefer editing files you could just leave `run_im ibus`, locally on `~/.xinputrc` or globally on `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out a solution by myself: iBus wasn't working and I was closing it from the tray unknowingly. I have edited my .xinputrc to allow iBus to start. Still, I don't know why on the other accounts it worked normally; I will mention the contents of the edited .xinputrc below.

```
# im-config(8) generated on Sun, 07 Feb 2016 00:01:26 +0200
run_im ibus
XIM=none
XIM_PROGRAM=
XIM_ARGS=
GTK_IM_MODULE=gtk-im-module-simple
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
IMSETTINGS_IGNORE_ME=yes
DISABLE_IMSETTINGS=yes
# im-config signiture: cce1d9f2a380733e9faadc73e8c273ee  -
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is most likely due to Keyboard input method not being set to "iBus".

Go to Applications -> System Tools -> Language and support.
On the Language tab, set "Keyboard input method" to "iBus".
Logout/login or restart computer, and it works :)

Comment: It was set to iBus but for some reason I was closing it without knowing that.