# Unicode input doesn't work in all applications

Tags: unicode-entry

Unicode input (by `Ctrl+Shift+u`) does not work in all applications. For example *[RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/)* and *[Notepadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/s/)* don't allow such input combination.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have *IBus* input method enabled in system language settings.

- Why does such issue occur with some apps?
- Is there a way to fix this?

**UPD**

Sometimes (but not everytime) there is additional strange behavior. When *RStudio* is running and its window is opened (i.e. not in minimized state), it may block unicode input in other applications' windows. This behaviour dissapears after minimizing *RStudio*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because is a [non-gtk application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash#comment707265_31283). Also, seems that [we lost that feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768191/how-does-one-enter-unicode-characters-into-systems-with-mir) completely on Ubuntu 16.04, with Mir.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Nevertheless unicode input perfectly works on a pure JavaFX interface too.