# I can use Alt-X to enter Unicode on an old machine. How is this possible?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode-entry

I dug out an old Acer Aspire E1-771 laptop and put Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 on it (just Ubuntu, no Windows). I now find I can use <kbd>Alt + X</kbd> to insert Unicode sequences even though I thought this was impossible. I am transcribing an old chemical document and can enter all the Unicode characters including 5-character ones with the letter F from a standard external keyboard without NumLock and without case sensitivity.

I cannot do this on any other machine running Ubuntu 18 or 19 (I have half a dozen computers).

I'd like to copy this feature to the other machines if I can find out the underlying mechanism.

Any explanations?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/a/31283/349837). If it doesn't work, check [if the input method system is iBus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050341/349837).

Comment: Hi Pablo,Thank you. Yes the latest build of LibreOffice seems to allow this but the main difference seems to be that I had the Esoterik font installed https://www.fontspace.com/cosmorama/esoterik on the machine that worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The standard ways to enter Unicode characters on Linux are

> - Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and type <kbd>u</kbd> followed by the hex digits. Then release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>.
> - Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, release, then type the hex digits, and press <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Space</kbd> or even on some systems, press and release <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11_(Linux_and_Unix_variants)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is supported by many applications though, like MS Word, Wordpad or Libre Office. Therefore I think you've used Libre Office on one system and type on some random textboxes on the other

However using typing the Unicode code points is just for typing rarely used characters. It isn't a good way for typing common characters. You should create a keyboard layout for your own that and access those special characters through [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key). Even better, you should use [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) which is more suitable for scientific documents. You can get any symbols easily with beautiful formatting and don't need to remember the Unicode code points