# Cedilha character in an english keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, 19.10

I used to have **ç** key on my Windows laptop by hitting the keys **'** + **c**.
I'am using Ubuntu 19:10 and can't find the keyboard layout with the same key sequence as Windows. I do find layouts where the key is in **AltGr** + **,** but not in **'** + **c**.

Do I need to install the layout or change the layout name (Universal, International or something else)?

**Settings > Region & Language**
System Language: English
Formats: Brasil

**Input Sources**
English (US)

Comment: Another example is when I press **'** + **e** results in **é**.

Comment: Use your Compose key (Sometime set as Right Windows key) which latches - release then follow with c and , in sequence.. ç and Compose e then ' for é

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key)

First install **Gnome Tweak** from **Ubuntu Software**.
Open **Gnome Tweak**, search menu for **Keyboard & Mouse**, find **Compose Key** option and enable it. You can change you Compose Key in there.

I manage to get **ç** by hitting `Compose Key` + `,` + `c`.