# International US layout with distribution for tildes and quotes similar to Mac

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I've acquired a US layout for my Ubuntu desktop and I've configured the keyboard with the US international layout. I also own a macbook and the layout is configured in a way that when I want to enter international characters like ñ, or the tilde (e.g. á, é, í or even è ù) I can do it from vowels or characters themselves. Sometimes I need to write simple or double quotes but in the configured Ubuntu layour I need to use the altGr key in order to enter it. Similarly, in Windows I have to press twice the key. Also annoying.

I think that my problem is that in Mac **the base US layout is kept and the international keys are what require a special combination of keys**. I'd like a similar configuration here in Ubuntu.

Edit:

- In mac if I want to write á I'd type: option + e (enter the tilde) + vowel.
- If I want to enter ñ I'd type: option + n (shows ~) + n.
- The best part in here is that I can write single and double quotes without weird combinations. I.e. the base US layout is kept, the international keys are what require a special combination of keys.

Is it possible to configure the layout similarly to the layout in mac?

Comment: How does Mac handle such characters?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I've edited my question to reflect the answer for your question... I hope this clarifies my issue!

Comment: GNOME's on-screen keyboard has something similar to how you describe that "option" feature of Mac, but I'm not aware of any XKB keyboard layout which works that way. Actually I think it would be very hard to mirror that functionality using XKB. Possibly it would be easier to provide a tip if you let us know more exactly which symbols you often type which you would like to enter in some other way than your selected layout offers. Using a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) might be part of a solution.

Comment: I use the compose key, https://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key?rq=1, it can be used for many characters, á ü, ñ, ½ and so on, even though sometimes the character is not on the list, I use CTRL + SHIFT + U then (hexadecimal-number) to type  the unicode directly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I needed to restart. Probably there's a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's a layout already for that, but it wasn't working immediately or **I had to restart**.

Select the **English International with Alt Gr dead keys** (without the *US* in the name) then restart your system. If you don't restart, the keyboard layout won't work.

Now I can type:

- <kbd>'</kbd> -> single quote
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> -> é
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> -> é
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> -> ñ
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> (so: <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>) -> ñ

This is exactly what I was looking for... but apparently you just need to restart.

Comment: What's your output of `localectl status`? With [current layout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680545/209677) set to us intl (with dead keys) and get é with just ', e... not all at the same time, which the + might imply

Comment: Didn't work in Linux Mint 21 (based on Ubuntu 22.04). Had to use a `US, intl., with dead keys` alternative (there's also [a way to make `'+c` give a `ç` instead of a `ć`](https://superuser.com/a/1235405/295116), but I haven't tried it yet).

Comment: Did you restart the system after selecting `English International with Alt Gr dead keys`?