# Why is the compose key (AltGr) disabled by default?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

The [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) (usually <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) is used to make it easier to insert alternate characters and symbols using easy to remember character sequences. Here is a useful list with the [available characters and symbols](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable).

This key is disabled by default in Ubuntu and can be enabled as shown here: [How can I enable Compose key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key)

But why is this key disabled by default in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The compose key is the key you define for the purpose and not necessarily <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>).
2. Many keyboard layouts use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> by default as a modifier to access 3rd and 4th level symbols included in the layout, and in those cases it's not suitable to define <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as a compose key.

I assume it's not enabled by default because there is no obvious key which would be suitable in all use cases. The key you define as a compose key stops working in its original way.