# Keyboard mapping

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Since I've upgraded to 20.04 LTS I'm no longer able to use AltGr key to write percentage sign, hash,at...etc. Also volume up/down wheel and media keys are no longer working.
I've changed the keyboard physically to a different model, but still the same.
In configuration, I've also changed keyboard type from Dell USB, to pc 102 intl and some other options but no difference.
Below showkey when I press volume wheel up, down and AltGr:

```
código de tecla 115 pulsada
código de tecla 115 liberada
código de tecla 114 pulsada
código de tecla 114 liberada
código de tecla 100 pulsada
código de tecla 100 liberada
```

Output from lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 413c:2011 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 413c:1005 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
```

Appreciate your guidance here....
Armando

Additional information as requested:

`setxkbmap -v -query`

```
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+–(user.dz)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc102)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc102
layout:     –
```

`env | grep -e 'LANG' -e 'LC_'`

```
LANGUAGE=es_ES
GDM_LANG=es_ES
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
```

After first try to install gnome-tweak-tools (aborted):

`setxkbmap -v -query`

```
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+es+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
rules:      evdev
model:      dellusbmm
layout:     es
```

... and funny thing is that now i can type #, @, |...

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting this my first post... I was not expecting all text being put together... I can paste showkey output again if required... thanks

Comment: I'm using Spanish language & layout (ES). Output posted.

Comment: sorry, user.dz, still need to learn how to do that nice formatting you do :-)

Comment: :) Here how to format it https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19392/26246 , it is called MarkDown

Comment: Probably looking for this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/70788/26246 , new releases seem to disable compose key and 3lvl shift on vanilla installation.

Comment: strange... i started running apt-get gnome-tweak-tool, but as it asked me something about a session manager, I aborted this install, ... and guess what... now i can type #@ :-)... in fact now my layout says ES.. i will paste in question. Also changed keyboard to dell Usb, but volume wheel still not working..

Comment: Changing layout, reset it. So it was  `layout:     –` for some reason.

Comment: mieeees... ok. I will keep on trying to set those media keys. Btw... who will mark this question as solved?.. or shall we leave it open while troubleshooting those media keys?

Comment: You Could submit an answer, see the large input box below. Check also [about]

Answer (score 0):

Not beeing able to find a reasonable way to make my standard dell multimedia usb keyboard work properly after the upgrade, I decided to install 20.04 again from scratch, and surprisingly, everything works as it should. Even odd behaviour with my old logitech camera and skype, it started to work normally since the very first moment.
No idea how upgrading from previous LTS could have created such a weird and undesireble behaviour.
Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge trying to fix this issue, but definitively, there were many other things in the background that probably were not working fine.